# Is it possible to apply a Creative Commons license to a multi-user web forum?

Tags: legal, licenses

My website will contain various posts, which may be posted by me or another user. Basically, it will be a sharing forum platform. My website contains different posts, and each post may contain different resources, such as their own image, file, etc., and each of those resources contains its own license (which grants me or another user permission to share the resources on my website).

Let's say I would like some protection for all the content of my website. I plan to apply a Creative Commons license since the content of my website will be free to all users. Can I still apply the CC license to my website in such a case since other licenses exist (for images, files, etc.)? To make things clearer, I am not seeking detailed licensing advice; I am just trying to get the basics of how licensing works for a website that may contain different resources.

Comment: I don't typically hear people describe CC licenses as "protecting" content, since they intuitively (at least to me) do the opposite - they strip away copyright protections that you are legally entitled to by default. Basically I equate CC licenses to "un-protecting" content, not protecting it. So my advice is just to be sure to research how the CC license protects or doesn't protect your content, as the semantics may be.

Comment: This may be better suited for law.stackexchange.com.  It seems to me you may have  a run into a problem as it almost seems you are attempting to usurp copyright on images created by your users.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I think I will further study more about the CC license, and I will try to seek advice from a lawyer to further understand this matter.